# What happens if you put swap space on a RAM disk?

Tags: swap, tmpfs

Since it's possible to create a RAM disk via `tmpfs`, and make it permanently available via `/etc/fstab`, what would happen if you had a post-boot script that created a swapfile on your freshly-minted RAM disk?

Suppose also there was no other swap available anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - no..only linux machines I have access to at the moment are prod servers :)

Comment: So the machines use some of their memory to get a ram disk and now you want to use some of that ram disk to get more memory?   I think buying more memory is a better idea.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - there are use cases where swap is required. Given enough physical RAM, *not* dedicating disk space for such would be preferable . See comments on the accepted answer (wherein [Vojtech Trefny](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/196468/vojtech-trefny) points to [zram](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/blockdev/zram.html) and Fedora's default [enabling of it in 33](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SwapOnZRAM)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have a very fast swap in RAM :-). But having swap in a RAM disk doesn't really make sense, having more RAM is better than having less RAM and fast swap. You can use [zram](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/blockdev/zram.html) and put swap on zram -- zram devices are compressed RAM block devices so you can effectively have 4 GiB swap on just 2 GiB zram device (so you are still using RAM for you swap, but less of it thanks to the compression). Fedora started configuring [swap on zram by default in Fedora 33](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SwapOnZRAM) and it works fine.

Also hibernation doesn't work with swap on zram (or any RAM based devices obviously) but that can be solved by multiple swap devices with the on-disk swap used for hibernation.

Comment: I'm not especially worried about hibernation - more of a question because some processes don't care how much RAM is available, they still want swap (for documented (or undocumented) reasons). For example, if. you have a machine with 2TB RAM, but some apps still want 32G or 64G swap ... putting it on a `tmpfs` RAM disk could make sense

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard about such use case, but it might make sense in this situation. [ramdisk](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/ramdisk.txt) might be better for this, you could use it directly for swap without creating a swapfile.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which application does that?

Comment: @Eduardo: I first ran into it with Java 1.4 & 1.6 apps - https://antipaucity.com/2011/08/08/why-technical-intricacies-matter

Comment: The VM is over-allocating, meaning that the extra memory will not ever be used by your application. You can (should?) use a normal disk swap, since putting it in memory would be a complete waste of RAM. The increased swap size is done just to avoid out-of-memory errors when the VM keeps on allocating more than the application asked for. You can then monitor swap usage to be sure it does not impact the application. It is not a requirement, it is a bug and if you had 1TB of memory you would not run into it.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani - you run into the issue (with that app) regardless of how much RAM you have ... *unless* you set its max RAM equal to its start RAM :). And yes - it *is* a requirement of that app (and some others I've run into) - it won't even install if swap isn't "sufficiently sized" :)